# Userform for Word with bookmarks and automated Crossreferences

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, userform

so this is my first programming experience and I am pretty excited about it. However, I have been dealing with a problem:

Goal

My goal is to create a word document with an integrated Userform asking for Name, Title and Startdate at the beginning. The information shall then be reflected in the defined areas in the document.

```
Dim Name As Range
Set Name = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Name").Range
Name.Text = Me.TextBox1.Value
Dim Title As Range
Set Title = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Title").Range
Title.Text = Me.TextBox2.Value
Dim Startdate As Range
Set Startdate = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Startdate").Range
Startdate.Text = Me.TextBox3.Value
Me.Repaint
UserForm1.Hide
```

I could successfully integrate the Userform, assigning the information to the bookmarks. Since I can only use 1 bookmark I tried my luck with text properties but it does not work.

The next thing I tried was to apply 1 bookmark and several cross-references throughout the text, meaning that I have to add a command to the code that updates all cross-references automatically I tried it with sub updateAllFields()

```
Dim Name As Range
    Set Name = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Name").Range
    Name.Text = Me.TextBox1.Value
    Dim Title As Range
    Set Title = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Title").Range
    Title.Text = Me.TextBox2.Value
    Dim Startdate As Range
    Set Startdate = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Startdate").Range
    Startdate.Text = Me.TextBox3.Value
    Me.Repaint
    Sub UpdateAllFields()
    UserForm1.Hide
```

But this one gives me an error message. Can somebody help, please?

Comment: Insufficient information: What do you mean by "can use only 1 bookmark"? What do you mean by "text properties"? What's the error message and which line of code triggers it? What's the content of `Sub UpdateAllFields`? And anyway, `Sub`` does *not* belong in a procedure: `Sub` is at the *start* of a procedure, only. In any case, you need to remove `sub ` from that second code sample...

Comment: Oh okay, so I can set only 1 bookmark in the document. If I want to copy that bookmark to another place it does not work....that's why I use Crossreference. Let's say I want the name to appear in 3 different places the bookmark just works for 1 space.

Comment: The error is Compile error:

Expected End Sub

There is no content in Updateallfields....shall I change it to 

    ...
    Me.Repaint
    ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
    UserForm1.Hide

Comment: Now I have the following cod but it deletes all my bookmarks :(

    Dim Name As Range
    Set Name = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Name").Range
    Name.Text = Me.TextBox1.Value
    Dim Title As Range
    Set Title = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Title").Range
    Title.Text = Me.TextBox2.Value
    Dim Startdate As Range
    Set Startdate = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Startdate").Range
    Startdate.Text = Me.TextBox3.Value
    Me.Repaint
    ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
    UserForm1.Hide

Comment: Note that you should use the [edit] link below the question to add / change information. FWIW when you write to a bookmark it will be deleted, but it can be re-created. If you include the code in the question, in a readable format, I can show you how this is done. Custom Document Properties may or may not be a good approach - it all depends on what is done with the end result.

Comment: Please remember to use @CindyMeister (a `"` plus the person's name) in order to "ping" people (put a message in the Inbox) when answering in Comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stick to the fields path as it may be less work to maintain.

---

### I: Create three custom document properties for each field (Name, Title, StartDate)

Steps: 
1) Click File | Properties | Advanced properties | Custom
2) Enter the following data:
- Name: customName
- Text: Enter name
3) Click the button "Add"
4) Repeat steps 2 and 3 for fields Title and StartDate (remember to add the "custom" word before so you can identify them later easily

This is how it should look like:
[image]

---

### II: Add the fields of each custom property created to the word document

Steps:
1) Position the cursor where you want the field in the word document
2) Click Insert | Quick parts | Field | Categories: Document information | DocProperty | < name of the doc property >
3) Click Ok
4) Repeat the process for each field

[image]

Note: You can add the same field / custom property, in different parts of the document

[image]

---

### III: Create the UserForm and add the controls

Steps:
1) Add the UserForm
2) Add three textboxes and set the name property to:
- txtName
- txtTitle
- txtStartDate
for each one.
3) Add a command button and set its name to cmdInsertData

This is how it should look like:

[image]

To set the name of each control look for (Name) at the properties window:

[image]

---

### IV: Add code to show the userform at startup

Steps:
1) Launch the VBE by pressing Alt + F11 (or activating the developer tab in the ribbon and pressing the Visual basic button
2) Add the following code to the "ThisDocument" object:

```
Private Sub Document_Open()

    UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

---

### V: Add the form code

Steps:
1) Right click the UserForm1 object and select "View Code"
2) Add the following code:

```
Private Sub cmdInsertData_Click()

    ' Update the properties values
    ThisDocument.CustomDocumentProperties("customName").Value = Me.txtName.Value
    ThisDocument.CustomDocumentProperties("customTitle").Value = Me.txtTitle.Value
    ThisDocument.CustomDocumentProperties("customStartDate").Value = Me.txtStartDate.Value

    ' Show changes of document properties in document
    ThisDocument.Fields.Update

    ' Hide the userform
    UserForm1.Hide

End Sub
```

Remember to save your document as macro-enabled

Close it and reopen it

Give it a try and let me know

Disclaimer: As [this article states](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/), there is a right way to handle showing a userform properly, but I'll leave it the "easy" way for simplicity purposes.

Comment: OMG it works. Thank you so much Ricardo. Your explanation is flawless and it worked on the 1st attempt.

Comment: I did...now I did it again. Can you confirm?

Comment: All set. Thank you.